# Solr -- forcing facet to show enum fields that aren't currently present in any document

Tags: solr

I have a field which can have known set of string values, and it is of **EnumField** type.

Is there a way to force **Solr** to return all facet values for it? The `facet.mincount=0` property only works if there are existing documents with corresponding facet field value, however they were filtered out in current search using e.g. fq.

However, if none current documents have that value, it doesn't show up at all.

---

Consider I have a field `type`, which is defined as an enum, and can have values `A` and `B`. And let's say I have imported such docs:

```
[{
 "name_s": "Doc 1",
 "type": "A",
 "user_s": "Foo"
}, {
 "name_s": "Doc 2",
 "user_s": "Bar"
}]
```

If I do a facet query on the field `type` using a filter query by user "Bar", the only facet value I am returned is "A" with the count of 0. My goal is to force it to return both values "A" and "B" in such scenario (and both having count 0).

Comment: do you want to see facet values even for documents that aren't matched by the query?

Comment: Yes, in particular when those facet values are defined as enum

Comment: could you elaborate on this?enum as predefined values? how would Solr know about your enum somewhere?

Comment: I'm specifically talking about solr's enum, as seen e.g. here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-enum-fields.html

Comment: yeah, but in this sense, EnumField is no different in terms of faceting as other field types, facets are calculated on matched docset only. I could think of some idea if you have fq that could be ignored and you want to return results ignoring it. Will it be ok?

Comment: I've added an example to my question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: My question is facet is for selection so that user can narrow down the search results. There is no use to show a facet to user for which results already not exist. If you really only need to know about the what terms type field has then you can check my answer if that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mailing list, this is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simple curious about to find all the terms present in field type you can easily find it using the term component of the Solr.

Doc : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-terms-component.html

Doc is for version 6.6 you can change it accordingly the version you are currently working on.

Here is sample url: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/terms?terms.fl=type

Comment: But that is not what the question is about - the question wants to include all the possible values for the EnumField, even if there is no documents that contain that value. The terms component will not return those values unless they're present in a document, which is the same case that the OP originally asked (and used faceting to achieve).

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by using [tagging and excluding filters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters):

You first tag your filter query: `fq={!tag=my_tag}user_s:Bar`

And then you use the exclude tag in your facet: `facet.field={!ex=my_tag}type`

Comment: This would only affect the *count* of facet values, but it wouldn't include missing keys. Again, there isn't a single document with the value of "B" for the `type` field; in other words, a query `type:B` would return an empty set.

The answer must resolve around the enum somehow, else how would solr know all the possible values?